# Unclassifiable statement at (1) in gfortran linux

Tags: linux, oop, fortran, gfortran, fortran90

I am elementary Fortran programmer in Linux(Ubuntu). I have a code that run with Intel Visual Fortran in Windows but when I try to compile this code with gfortran on Linux I get this error:

```
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
```

My code is :

```
    module mesh
     type::meshreader
      private
      integer::NF
      integer::y
      contains
      procedure , public :: getNF
      end type
      contains
      function getNF(this)    
      class(meshreader) :: this
       integer :: getNF
        getNF = this.NF
        end function
        end module

     Implicit None

      print*, 'Hello'
        End
```

I think gfortran can not know this line of code: getNF = this.NF.
Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Fortran has benn spelled this way for more thsn 30 years. Please learn how to get your indentation consistent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Structure components in Fortran are not selected using a dot but using `%` (`this%NF`).

The dot notation is only offered by some compilers as an extension, but it is highly non-standard. I suggest avoiding it.

What is the `%` character used for is summarized in [What does "%" mean / do in Fortran?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100131/what-does-mean-do-in-fortran)

Comment: tnx for your help .