# Printing members of parent type from an instance of an extended type

Tags: linux, debugging, fortran, gdb, gfortran

**Scenario (see the code below):** consider some Fortran module `my_module` which contains the definition of two derived types: `test` (parent) and `sub_test` (extends `test`, subclass). In addition to the two members `a` and `b` of the parent class, `sub_test` defines a new member `c`. Eventually, this module `my_module` is to used in some program `my_program`.

```
module my_module

implicit none

private
public :: test, sub_test

type :: test
  integer :: a = 1
  integer :: b = 2
end type test

type, extends(test) :: sub_test
  integer :: c = 3
contains
  procedure, public :: increment
end type sub_test

contains

subroutine increment (this)
class(sub_test) :: this
this % a = this % a + 1
write(*, *) "Incrementation complete!"
end subroutine increment

end module my_module
!---------------------------------------
program my_program

use my_module

implicit none

type(test)  :: parent
type(sub_test) :: child

write(*, *) "Printing parent members"
write(*, *) parent % a, parent % b
write(*, *) "Printing child members"
write(*, *) child % a, child % b, child % c

call child % increment

end program my_program
```

**Objective:** When debugging, using `gdb`, we want to print the values of the parent members `a` and `b` of some variable of the child (extended) type `sub_test`. In sum, we're looking for a successful completion of something like:

```
(gdb) print child % a
```

yet, apparently, it is not that trivial.

**Setup before trying to print:**

- Compile the program (here called `test.f90`) with the `-g` flag, convenient for the application of `gdb` with `gfortran -g test.f90 -o a.out`
- Run the executable with `gdb ./a.out`
- Insert a breakpoint a breakpoint in the last `write(*, *)` statement of the program and in the unique `write(*, *)` statement in subroutine `increment` and run the program

```
(gdb) break test.f90:41
Breakpoint 1 at 0xb12: file test.f90, line 41.
(gdb) break test.f90:24
Breakpoint 2 at 0x955: file test.f90, line 24.
(gdb) run
```

**What I have (*unsuccessfully*) tried so far:**

- Print directly the members from the `child` variable (member `c` prints flawlessly)

```
Breakpoint 1, my_program () at test.f90:41
41  write(*, *) child % a, child % b, child % c
(gdb) p child%a
There is no member named a.
(gdb) p child%b
There is no member named b.
(gdb) p child%c
$1 = 3
```

- Print the `test` (parent) member of the `child` variable, as `gdb` shows it exists
- Print the so-wanted members from the `test` member of `child`

```
Breakpoint 1, my_program () at test.f90:41
41  write(*, *) child % a, child % b, child % c
(gdb) p child
$2 = ( test = ( a = 1, b = 2 ), c = 3 )
(gdb) p child%test
A syntax error in expression, near `test'.
(gdb) p child%test%a
A syntax error in expression, near `test%a'.
(gdb) p child%test%b
A syntax error in expression, near `test%b'.
```

- The same steps above, but this time applied at the breakpoint inside the subroutine, therefore, trying to print the members of the dummy variable `this`. In this case, `gdb` clearly changes the pitch regarding the variable and, for instance, `c` can only be accessed through the hidden member `_dat`, yet `a` and `b` continue unreachable.

```
Breakpoint 2, my_module::increment (this=...) at test.f90:24
24  write(*, *) "Incrementation complete!"
(gdb) p this
$3 = ( _data = 0x555555756018 <child>, _vptr = 0x555555755d20 <__my_module_MOD___vtab_my_module_Sub_test> )
(gdb) p this%_data
$4 = (PTR TO -> ( Type sub_test )) 0x555555756018 <child>
(gdb) p this%_data%a
There is no member named a.
(gdb) p this%_data%b
There is no member named b.
(gdb) p this%_data%c
$5 = 3
(gdb) p this%_data%test%a
A syntax error in expression, near `test%a'.
(gdb) p this%_data%test%b
A syntax error in expression, near `test%b'.
```

**Thank you for reading:** I feel like reaching a dead-end in this regards, I deeply hope someone could lend me a hand. `gdb` seems incredible but, without being able to inspect this information, I sadly fear it won't suit my needs properly.

**More information:** I am using `gdb-9.2` and `gfortran 7.5.0`.

Comment: Q: What does the `%` in `child%test` mean?

Comment: @paulsm4, `%` in this case is a [part reference separator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8100131/3157076): "the `test` component of object `child`". (In this case `test` is the parent component, referring to the type being extended.)

Comment: The test case doesn't compile for me (using gfortran 9.3), and I don't know how to fix it. Does single-quoting the accessor help? E.g. `print 'child%test'`.

Comment: @EmployedRussian there was a small bug in the code. I edited the post with the fix and now you should be able to compile it. Unfortunately, single-quoting did not help, it appears to be printing a string `$5 = 'child%test'`.

Comment: I guess `gdb` is basically irrelevant, what you want to do is your main program (or another module using `my_module`) being able to have access to `a` from the child type, right? There are several options and I can post a detailed answer describing the ways you can do it - if that's what you need to do.

Comment: @Pap my question specifically addresses how can one achieve so within `gdb`. In fact, if you run the sample program, I can access `a` simply via `child % a` (see `write(*, *) child % a, child % b, child % c`).

Comment: @AntónioCarneiro In this particular case, it is ok to have access to parent or child members just like that. But I am guessing this is just a simplified example and the real thing is way more complicated. In that case, making type members public is almost always a very bad idea. I would make `a` and `b` private, and add functions like `getA` and `incrementA` instead of relying on hidden, compiler-specific variables like `_dat`.. Otherwise I don't see what's the point of using derived types when you ignore data hiding. Try implementing `child%getA()`. If nothing else, gdb might like that more.

Comment: @Pap perhaps we are talking about slightly different things. I am aware of the benefits of encapsulation and, in fact, I use it on a regular basis. Here, however, I am not particularly interested in being able to get the members within the program but within `gdb` itself. My ultimate goal is to print those members `a` and `b` during a `gdb` session. I might be mistaken, but it seems that the `public` and `private` attributes do not affect the way one can interact with the members of the derived type, again, within `gdb`.

Comment: At least related from the gdb bugzilla https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=22497

Comment: @IanBush That seems exactly the case. Have you heard of some related bugfix? That was reported about 3 years ago.

Comment: Sorry, that link contains all of my knowledge of this issue. Suggest you submit this as another bug - it is not quite the same but I suspect the root cause is identical

Comment: I have submitted a new bug issue to [https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=26373](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=26373).