# Understanding different types in Fortran

Tags: visual-studio, fortran, intel-fortran

I was reading a Fortran code, came across the following code, couldn't understand what it does.

```
m%AllOuts( BAzimuth(k) ) = m%BEMT_u(indx)%psi(k)*R2D
```

I know that % here works like a pipe indicator to access values in a way similar to a dictionary in Python. I have a dictionary **m** let's say and the first key is AllOuts, but what does anything inside parentheses mean? Is it like another dictionary?

Comment: For completeness can you include the definition of `m` and any associated types.

Comment: You might want to read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8100169/10774817) about derived types in Fortran.

Comment: I added in the comments below @JAlex 
Thanks for your response.

Comment: @thisismihir please [edit] the question to add the definition of `m` so that someone else can be helped in the future. Comments are not the right place for this.

Comment: @JAlex 
`m%AllOuts( RtAeroPwr ) = m%BEMT_u(indx)%omega * m%AllOuts( RtAeroMxh )`
How can I print the values of `m%BEMT_u(indx)%omega` and `m%AllOuts( RtAeroMxh )` 
They are probably arrays. How can I print them? 
I tried this `print *, m%AllOuts( RtAeroMxh ), m%AllOuts, m%BEMT_u` 
Had few errors. Should I share the errors?

Comment: Please [edit] the question with this information and remove it from the comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The percent sign is not denoting a dictionary. There are no native dictionaries in Fortran.

The percent sign denotes the component of a type. For example:

```
! Declare a type
type :: rectangle
    integer :: x, y
    character(len=8) :: color
end type rectangle

! Declare a variable of this type
type(rectangle) :: my_rect

! Use the type

my_rect % x = 4
my_rect % y = 3
my_rect % color = 'red'

print *, "Area: ", my_rect % x * my_rect % y
```

The parentheses could either indicate the index of an array, or the arguments of a call.

So, for example:

```
integer, dimension(10) :: a

a(8) = 16     ! write the number 16 to the 8th element of array a
```

Or, as a prodedure:

```
print *, my_pow(2, 3)

...

contains

function my_pow(a, b)
    integer, intent(in) :: a, b
    my_pow = a ** b
end function my_pow
```

In order to figure out what `m` is, you'd need to look at the declaration of `m`, which would be something like

```
type(sometype) :: m
```

or

```
class(sometype) :: m
```

Then you'd need to find out the type declaration, which would be something like

```
type :: sometype
    ! component declarations in here
end type
```

Now one of the components, `BEMT_u`, is almost certainly an array of a different type, which you'd also need to look up.

Comment: One may have to look for other types of things to determine what `m` is.  `m` could be implicitly typed, or it could be a selector in one of several constructs.  And if it's not a local entity it could be from a quite distant host or module.

Comment: This helps a lot @chw21. Thanks for this. 
I looked for m, I came across the following

`TYPE(AD_MiscVarType),      INTENT(IN   )  :: m  ! misc variables`

But this is inside subroutines. Now when I looked for AD_MiscVarType, I came across this

`TYPE, PUBLIC :: AD_MiscVarType:: AD_MiscVarType`

`REAL(ReKi) , DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE  :: AllOuts`

I'm not sure what type of AD_MiscVarType is being allocated twice.

Comment: @francescalus @chw21 
`m%AllOuts( RtAeroPwr ) = m%BEMT_u(indx)%omega * m%AllOuts( RtAeroMxh )`
How can I print the values of `m%BEMT_u(indx)%omega` and `m%AllOuts( RtAeroMxh )` 
They are probably arrays. How can I print them? 
I tried this `print *, m%AllOuts( RtAeroMxh ), m%AllOuts, m%BEMT_u` 
Had few errors. Should I share the errors?